# C Converting int to char and add dot

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

It seems simple but I don't know how to do this.
What I have tried is `printf("%d.", i);` but since the real code needs padding, the real code turns like this `printf("%-4d.", i);` and therefore it goes like this: `"1   ."`
What I want is `"1.   "`
Any solutions?

Edit: If you can't see what I mean, I want the spaces after the dot, not before the dot. This is all for the sake of tidy output.
Another edit: I've also tried adding spaces after the dot itself, it looks horrible since it always print the same amount of spaces. With indentation, it controls the space output.

Comment: @4386427: Read the question again.

Comment: @4386427 then it won't be tidy. This is going to list a hundred of variable, so imagine if it was "1.   Name" it will be "100.   Name". I want it to be "1.   Name" and "100. Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically doing string manipulations and then padding the result.  Create a temporary buffer to hold the string, and then pad that when you print it.

```
char buf[20];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d.", i);
printf("%-5s", buf);
```

Comment: Whoops. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Do you mind explaining abit about it? As I can't find much info on snprintf().

Comment: The `snprintf` function prints into a string, instead of printing into a file.  It's the same as `printf` or `fprintf` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this: `printf("%d.%*c", i, number_of_spaces, ' ');`

It's ugly but it fixes your problem.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing 'ugly' about it. It is the correct use of a *minimum filed width* modifier to the `printf` *format string* specifying the width of the character field to be filled with `spaces`.

Comment: Glad you liked ! :)

Comment: But you have to calculate the `number_of_spaces` depending on the value of `i` on your own.

Comment: I've also tried your code, it's not ugly, but it's just simply making things harder for me.. Since as @Gerhardh mentioned, you have to calculate the value of `number_of_spaces` depending on `i` on your own. Atleast using the snprintf, it does everything for me, I am a student of Computer Science but I hate doing tons of calculation on my own :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. You could write to an auxiliary string:

```
char buf[12];

snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d.", i);
printf("%-5s", buf);
```

Alternatively, you could use the fact that `printf` returns the number of chars that were printed, so you could do the padding by hand:

```
int n = printf("%d.", i);

while (n++ < 5) putchar(' ');
```

Comment: the second one is a clean solution.